# Why the query below is giving only the total(i.e. Smart+NonSmartSessions) for each of SmartRouterSessions and NonSmartRouterSessions?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

```
SELECT  MAX(TO_CHAR(DTM_LAST_MODIFIED,'MM/DD/YYYY')) As JobCompletionDate,
             MAX(TO_CHAR(DTM_LAST_MODIFIED,'HH24:MI:SS')) As JobCompletionTime,
             COUNT('Select * from wfimgr.device_usage where  SERVICE_NAME in ("WIFILOC9","WIFIDEV9")') As SmartRouterSessions,
             COUNT('Select * from wfimgr.device_usage where SERVICE_NAME NOT IN ("WIFILOC9","WIFIDEV9")') As NonSmartRouterSessions
FROM wfimgr.device_usage WHERE DTM_LAST_MODIFIED BETWEEN '28-MAR-2014' AND '29-MAR-2014'
```

Comment: Oracle does not dynamically execute the SQL in the `COUNT` function. What you have is no different than `count(*)` or `count(1)` or `count('yellow dogs')`.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably get you what you intended:

```
SELECT MAX(TO_CHAR(DTM_LAST_MODIFIED, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) As JobCompletionDate,
       MAX(TO_CHAR(DTM_LAST_MODIFIED, 'HH24:MI:SS')) As JobCompletionTime,
       sum(case when service_name in ('WIFILOC9','WIFIDEV9') then 1 else 0 end) as SmartRouterSessions
       sum(case when service_name not in ('WIFILOC9','WIFIDEV9') then 1 else 0 end) as NonSmartRouterSessions
  FROM wfimgr.device_usage
 WHERE DTM_LAST_MODIFIED BETWEEN '28-MAR-2014' AND '29-MAR-2014'
```